# My htacess file is not working despite my configuration

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am tired of seeing my urls look dirty eg. http://localhost/test/postsingle?tk=Ben Affleck and Jennifer Garner File For Divorce Amid Reconciliation Rumors

so I am currently trying to make it look like this eg

http://localhost/test/postsingle/Ben Affleck and Jennifer Garner File For Divorce Amid Reconciliation Rumors

But its not working this my htacess config below
Please I will be really grateful for an answer

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^politicssingle/(\d+)*$ ./politicssingle?tk=$1
RewriteRule ^postsingle/(\d+)*$ ./postsingle?tk=$1
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search?query=$1
```

Though I've seen related questions here but they're not helping

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php remove this line and then try

Comment: same thing, still not working

Comment: kindly check in your server configuration that wether it considers htaccess or not

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule in that file that even tries to rewrite the requests you ask about. So why should they get rewritten?

I'd say that you probably need to replace the first rewrite rule like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?test/postsingle/(.+)/? /test/postsingle?tk=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).